# Why getting incorrect results from an OpenMP program?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm writing some simple example to understand how the things work with OpenMP programs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main (int argc ,char* argv[]){
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    int j =0;
    #pragma omp parallel private (j)
    {
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<2;i++){
        printf("from thread %d : i is equel to  %d and j is equal to %d\n ",omp_get_thread_num(),i,j);

    }
    }
}
```

So in this example I should get **`j=0` each time**,
unfortunately the result is **`j == 0` 3 times** , and **`j == 32707`** one time.

**What is wrong with my example?**

Comment: Try with firstprivate (j) rather than private (j) to ensure that each private copy of j has the same value (0) assigned to it.

Comment: yes youa re right , thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `firstprivate(j)` rather than `private(j)` if you want that each thread has a private copy of **`j`** with the initial value being the value before entering the parallel region.